# Add a break line after submiting values in react/redux application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I am pretty new to redux/react. My application is simple: user fills three input values and by pressing the button it outputs to the screen. The problem is that I can't find the way how to put the line break after every submit.

this is my actions file update.js:

```
export const SAVE_TEXT = 'SAVE_TEXT'
    let nextId = 1;
export function saveText(name, date, scenario) {
  return {
    type: SAVE_TEXT,
    name,
    date,
    scenario,
    id: nextId++
  }
}
```

this is my reducers file update.js:

```
import { SAVE_TEXT } from '../actions/update'
import Immutable from 'immutable'

export default (state = Immutable.List(['']), action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case SAVE_TEXT:
      return state.push(action.name, ' ', action.date, ' ', action.scenario)
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

this is the main file Update.js:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'

class Update extends Component {
  handleClick(e) {
    this.refs.projectName.value = ''
    this.refs.reportingDate.value = ''
    this.refs.scenario.value = ''
  }
  render() {
    const { saveText, update } = this.props
    return (
      <p>
        Project name
        <input type='text' ref='projectName' />
        Reporting date
        <input type='text' ref='reportingDate' />
        Scenario
        <input type='text' ref='scenario' />
        <button onClick={(e) => { saveText(this.refs.projectName.value, this.refs.reportingDate.value, this.refs.scenario.value); this.handleClick(e)} }>
         Submit Project
        </button>
        <br/><br/>
        {update}
        {' '}
      </p>
    )
  }

}

export default Update
```

I have added the picture how does it look now. I would like to add a break line after every new submit. I tried to add it in my reducers file but it doesn't work this way.

[image]

Comment: it's unclear what `update` is - a string? You're outputting it like it was a string but it looks like SAVE_TEXT pushes on to an array? You didn't show the part of the code which actually creates this prop..

Comment: it is an array. look at my reducers file update.js:   
      return state.push(action.name, ' ', action.date, ' ', action.scenario)

Answer (score 1):

You can map it and wrap it in a `<p>`.

```
{update.map(scenario => <p>{scenario}</p>)}
```

P.S. it might make more semantic sense to call `update` `scenarios` instead

Comment: with map it adds a break line after each property: name, date and scenario. how to put a break line only after the scenario?

Comment: Do `state.push(action.name + ' ' + action.date + ' ' + action.scenario)`. Or using ES6 template strings: ``state.push(`${action.name} ${action.date}  ${action.scenario}`)`` or `state.push([action.name, action.date, action.scenario].join(' '))`.. Basically push a string each time

Comment: Np, please accept the answer if it solved the problem for you